# Domain price after first year

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

If you buy a domain somewhere, and it costs 1€/year for the first year and then 70€/year but you transfer the domain to another registrar before the year ends to another domain registrar where it costs 20€/year, how much do you have to pay after the first year?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the registrar. Typically the price will be similar or a little more than the new registration or transfer rate. Most registrars also provide a pricing table for the 3 common actions - Create/Register, Renew and Transfer

To find the lowest price, you can visit http://domcomp.com. Search for the domain extension/TLD for your domain and check the prices.

Comment: Please know it is not always about price. We have seen here again and again where the cheap option was not a good option. You MUST go for quality first. With prices so low throughout the entire industry, who can complain about buying top quality??

Comment: @closetnoc I agree and that's a fair point but lower price does not necessarily mean lower quality. For important infra like domains/hosting, necessary research must always be performed to determine the reliability, stability, and quality of the provider. I was just not commenting on those aspects as the discussion would then digress in a different direction. I wanted to retain the answer to the point of the question

Comment: You are right about price and quality. However, there is a point where price signals quality. It is impossible to provide quality services for some of the prices out there - they get you somewhere. On the opposite side of the scale there is Network Solutions which has been rather poor for years and charges the highest prices out there. I used to be a web host and one of the first registered ISPs in the business. I even represented U.S. Robotics to the ISP world at ISPOne. Free or cheap usually means cutting corners. But then again, a higher price does not mean the company is good either.

Answer (score 1):

> how much do you have to pay after the first year?

If the registrar you transfer the domain to charges 20€/year (for *renewals*) then you will pay 20€ after the first year.

Some TLDs (notably `.com`) require you to pay for an additional years registration at the time of transfer, which then extends your registration period.

However, be careful of registrars that offer low initial registrations and then charge you an additional "admin" fee to transfer out. Check the T&Cs.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is the 90 day transfer rule. You cannot transfer a domain from one registrar to another within 90 days. So if you decide to transfer and then do not like the new registrar you have to wait 90 days before moving to yet another registrar.